# Hosted Database v Cloud Database

Tags: mysql, database, cloud

I have looked everywhere...
whats the difference between a hosted database and a cloud database they seem like the same things?

Thanks

Comment: they are the same thing.

Comment: surely they both need the use of the internet to store and retrieve information

Comment: Depends on which "hosted database" and "cloud database" you're comparing.

Comment: The outsourced database (ODB) model is an example of
the well-known Client-Server model. In the ODB model,
the Database Service Provider (also referred to as the
Server) has the infrastructure required to host outsourced
databases and provides efcient mechanisms for clients to
create, store, update and query the database.

Comment: That description fits both cloud and hosted databases. Both are hosted  by an external service provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "hosted database" and "cloud database" mean that the database lives on the servers of some external provider/hoster.

The hoster might even be the same in both cases.
The main difference is that the "cloud" plans are usually meant to scale more (at a higher monthly fee), so you'd use them when you expect your site to get huge soon and need to quickly adjust server capacity when needed.

On the other hand, "hosted" plans are not that expensive, but have more limitations (server speed, database size...) and are more suited for "small" websites.

Of course this isn't by any means an "official" description of the two terms, but that's the impression that I get every time I see "cloud" or "hosted" webspaces/databases/services/whatever.

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot in my understanding!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context in which they're being used, but, yes, they usually mean the same thing. When I see the term cloud database being used they are usually referencing some cloud platform like Amazon EC2 or Microsoft Azure instead of GoDaddy or HostGator or something. Plus, cloud is the new buzz word - I'm sure it sells better. Lol.

Comment: My tutor said talk about...

traditional databases (reltational, distributed etc.)
then HOST DATABASES?
Then talk about cloud databases?

Comment: its my dissertation and it talks about security in cloud computing systems

Comment: A quick Google brought me this article which may be of interest to your learning - http://www.itnewsafrica.com/2011/04/cloud-vs-hosted-services/ if you are trying to clearly identify differences between the two.

Comment: You're doing a dissertation in this and you're asking us?

Comment: @RyanKempt Thanks for that link its helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As Christian Specht said, the cloud servers really scale more. So why you need more scaling? and why there are many featured options in cloud database service selection?

Things are not like before. Before smartphones and earlier pc operating systems, users gets information from the server only when they log on the specific web page using their credentials. But now apps like facebook shows notifications, provide ads etc and collect/push other data in parallel while we are looking at something else irrelevant.

Hosted database are reliable to access the database when users log onto the web page. But in case of the lastest smart phone applications, it needs to access the database everytime starting from its birth (installation on the device). So for each installation, the minimum workload over the server is expected to raise up.

So more scalability is required here. More simultaneous connections, Input/Output operation requests are expected daily. So with the dedicated servers with the core purpose, and with the configurable package selection based on your expectation of user count and bandwidth usage, **Cloud Service** is not yet another marketing term, but is a helpful service.